# jsp - set value of input tag (html) from a java string

Tags: html, jsp, input

I'm facing a strange problem here. The situation is like this:

I'm trying to set a value for an `input` tag from a java string:

```
   <input type="text" name="line" value=<%=line%>  ></input>

line = "this is my new line"
```

the result is that **value** is getting only the first word("this") and not the whole string.

anyone knows why or how to make it right??

Comment: use **double quotes**

Answer (score 3):

Put double quotes around the value like this -

```
<input type="text" name="line" value="<%=line%>"></input>
```

HTML uses space to separate different attributes/tags.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="line" value="<%=line%>"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody said use double quotes

```
<input type="text" name="line" value=<%=line%>  ></input>
```

The above line is only for correct your line and,if possible please do not use scriplets.Those are expired.

Please go through this [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Welcome  :) Mark it as answer,if helpful