# date and time object displaying only date in jsp table for input type text

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I am displaying arraylist data as table content in jsp. current code:

```
<td><input id="createDateStr<%=i+1%>" disabled="disabled" type="text" readonly value=<%= a.getCreateDateStr()%> /></td>
```

Here this code displays only the date and not the time. upon inspecting the element in browser i got this :

```
<input id="createDateStr1" disabled="disabled" type="text" readonly="" value="06/02/2017" 12:34:25>
```

Here we you see only the date is coming under the quotes as such it's displaying only the date. in the inspect option of the browser i removed the quotes after the date and put it at the end of the time and i can see the time as well.

but the object has both date and time, since running this code <%= a.getCreateDateStr()%> outside of the td gave me 06/02/2017 12:34:25

Comment: How does your `getCreateDateStr` method look like?

Comment: this link solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029843/jsp-set-value-of-input-tag-html-from-a-java-string